# How to avoid assigning same str to a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I found this difficult to handle.

I have a big pipeline which in a small section of it I perform a loop in a way to assign values as a list using `my_dict.setdefault(k1, []).append(v1)` but I want to have an if statement to say if a value already exists inside a list for a key then do not append it.

The part of my script is:

```
identifier1={}

for k1, v1 in fw1.items():
    #find_while_mismatch is a custom def
    idf1 = find_while_mismatch(v1, my_string)  #creates different versions of v1 and does re.search
    if idf1 is not None:  #skip return None
        identifier1.setdefault(k1, []).append(idf1)
```

I tried `identifier1 = defaultdict(set)` but it did not work, values inside list are still repeated.

I replaced line 3 with the line below but it does not work also.

```
if idf1 is not None and str(idf1) not in [i for i in identifier1.get(k1)]:
```

How can I make this to work? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're data type is `str`? why are you casting to `str` before check but appending the value itself to list. Either removing this cast or adding the cast at `.append(str(idf1))` should work (although it's not optimal)

Comment: FWIW, `[i for i in identifier1.get(k1)]` is superfluous and can be reduced to just `identifier1.get(k1)`.

Comment: @deceze you are right but when I do ```identifier1.get(k1)``` it prints a list with all values inside. With that said ```if idf1 not in identifier1.get(k1)``` does not help me.

Comment: and just need to add that including ```[i for i in identifier1.get(k1)]``` gives the error --> ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable```

Comment: *"values inside list are still repeated"* - Huh? With `defaultdict(set)` you shouldn't even *have* a list anymore.

Comment: @superbrain give it a shot

Comment: @Apex You can see it in M. Perier--Dulhoste's answer: no lists.

Comment: @superbrain yes you are right, I missed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using `identifier1 = defaultdict(set)` + `identifier1[k1].add(idf1)` can do the job. Indeed, the following snippet should work:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

identifier1 = defaultdict(set)

for k1, v1 in fw1.items():

    idf1 = find_while_mismatch(v1, my_string)

    if idf1 is not None:
        identifier1[k1].add(idf1)
```

---

I don't have all the information / variables defined (`fw1`, `find_while_mismatch`, ...) so I tried to use a dummy example:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

fw1 = {
   "key1": ["aaa", None, "aaa", "b"],
   "key2": ["a", None, None]
}


identifier1 = defaultdict(set)

for k1, v1 in fw1.items():
   for idf1 in v1:
      if idf1 is not None:
         identifier1[k1].add(idf1)

print(identifier1)
```

And the output is:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'key1': {'aaa', 'b'}, 'key2': {'a'}})
```

---

**Edit**: use a list instead of set

With some small changes, you can have it working with lists instead sets: you have to add one step to ensure the item is not in a list. You can have 2 solutions for this:

1. Use a `defaultdict(list)` for `identifier1` (Recommended)

```py
from collections import defaultdict

identifier1 = defaultdict(list)

for k1, v1 in fw1.items():

    idf1 = find_while_mismatch(v1, my_string)

    if idf1 is not None and idf1 not in identifier1[k1]:
        identifier1[k1].append(idf1)
```

2. Without the `defaultdict`

```py
identifier1 = {}

for k1, v1 in fw1.items():

    idf1 = find_while_mismatch(v1, my_string)
    items = identifier1.get(k1, [])
    if idf1 is not None and idf1 not in items:
        items.append(idf1)
        identifier[k1] = items
```

I think you had an issue with `.get` because you are not using a default value: the output of `identifier.get(k1)` is `None` if `k1` is not in `identifier`. In python, when you do `item in None`, you get a `TypeError` (since `None` is not iterable). So if you want to use `.get` you have to use an empty list as default value (e.g. `identifier1.get(k1, [])`)

Comment: Thank you for your help :), for learning purpose would you please tell the reason why my approach was not giving an expected answer?

Comment: Sure! In the snippet you posted, you are only checking if the item is None or not. However, you also have to check if the item is already in a the list or not to ensure you do not have duplicates. For the other approaches you mentioned (`defaultdict(set)` and using `get`) I don't have any information to tell you why it is not working. It depends if you change other lines in your snippet. I will update my answer to show how we can have it working with list!

Comment: That would be great :) Thank you - anyway I do not know why my question has been voted -1, was not my question a real problem? strange :/

Comment: I edited my answer to use lists instead of sets, tell me if something is not clear! I think the only problem with your question is that you mentioned what you tried but not the 2 corresponding snippets (even if there was minor changes it is always helpful). I acknowledge it is a little bit harsh to downvote your question only for this